# What is the Binder class in System.Reflection for?

Tags: c#, .net

I notice that there is a `Binder` class resided in the `System.Reflection` namespace of .NET. I read through the documentation on MSDN, but I am still not very what it does and how I can use it.

I did a search on Google but the word binding is alluded to "Data binding". By binding, does it mean "Data Binding"? If so, how can I use it for data binding then? I am hoping to find a simple or easy-to-understand example on its usage.

Thanks!

Comment: I'll be frank: I do a **lot** of reflection and binding work. I've never had to do any custom binding. I've seen them used occasionally, but from what I've seen they usually add complexity when the better option is to make things *simpler*.

Comment: By binding, do you mean data binding used between properties? Or is there a different definition of binding in such a scenario?

Comment: It is talking about *reflection* binding - not really data-binding (which has a separate API in a different namespace); i.e. what method gets selected if you use `someType.GetMethod(...)` passing in a `Binder`, and how the arguments are converted to the method's parameters. Very few people need anything unusual here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Binder` selects a member from a list of candidates, and performs type conversion from actual argument type to formal argument type ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.binder.aspx)).

You are also able to create your own binder.

Also quoted from this [page](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/getting-net-class-info-with-reflection/1050654)

> A `System.Reflection.Binder` object, which controls such things as type coercion and appropriate overloaded method selection. In most cases you’ll be able to pass null and use the default binder.

Comment: Thanks! But I still don't understand how I can use it, and in what situation do I use it for.

Comment: See the remarks section of the `Binder` methods. For example `BindToMethod` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.binder.bindtomethod.aspx). I never used it...